# worflow git: rebase to clean commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm planning a work flow to use with git. I have not worked with git yet, so I don't known if it is even possible to do.

That's express how I would like to keep my branchs:

I have two remote branchs: the **master** branch and a **develop** branch

For each new task I want to create a new **local branch** from **develop**, do a first commit with the ID of my task, then work on it and make a few commits that express the evolution of my work.
When I finish the task I want to merge the **local branch** into **develop** and push the **develop**.

When a new release will be created I want to merge the **develop** into **master** and use a interactive rebase to keep just the first commit of each task into the **master** and *fix up* non important commits. Finally, create a tag to mark the release point.

At the end of this scenarios I will have a **develop** branch which contains all historical commits and a **master** that just have a commit for each task and the tag marking the release.

At the first time I rebased the **master** everything worked fine: tag created, commits working good, the problem happened when I merged the **develop** into **master** to create a second release. All the older commits that I marked as *fix up* came back.

Did I do something wrong? there is a way to do what I want with git? I am mistaking the way how to use git?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invent the wheel.
Use **[git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)**.

**[Here](http://www.slideshare.net/lemiorhan/git-and-git-workflow-models-as-catalysts-of-software-development)** you can view an excellent presentation described in details.

Comment: Thanks for answer me @jsexpert, but this git flow that you showed me is quite complex. My team is migrating from svn and no one have worked with git before. I need something really simple, in order to minimize the traumas.